# Removing duplicate title tags and .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a lot of duplicate title tags showing in Google Webmaster Tools for my site.
My wordpress 3.6.1 plugin settings have my site domain url set to http://sitename.com in the general settings. My permalinks are set to /%postname%

How can I get rid of them?

They appear like this. 
/horror/santa-sangre-film-review/
/horror/santa-sangre-film-review

Comment: They appear like this? `yoursite.com/horror/santa-sangre-film-review/ /horror/santa-sangre-film-review`?  Please clarify more.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Wordpress **Settings > Permalinks** & Change your permalink settings to **'Post Name'** instead of `%postname%` - See the following Screenshot, i attached, for help

---

[image: See the screenshot]

I hope this helps.